# Nmake: Placeholder/Wildcards in Targets

Tags: placeholder, nmake

I already have a Makefile to build my software on Linux. But now i need a .mak file to build on Windows.

However, it's not possible to use Placeholders in Nmake like this way:

```
build: mytarget_foo
    #target build

mytarget_%:
    #target mytarget_% to match mytarget_foo
```

How to use placeholders in Nmake?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: console output:

> 'MAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'mytarget_foo
>   Stop.

Answer (score 0):

Use the asterisk. [Here's the doc.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18aeyde5.aspx)

```
mytarget_*:
    # target mytarget_* to match mytarget_foo
```

Comment: This does not work on my system (nmake.exe shipped with VS 2017), and in fact the documentation states that the wildcards are **expanded in dependency lines**, not that they are **matched against the rule names**, which I understand is what OP wanted to do (and is definitely what I want to do 7 years later).